# jQuery & PHP: Encode & Decode URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uri, urlencode

I am passing a string through a URL to another page whenever a link is clicked.

**The original `a` tag and its `href` are created via a PHP while loop as follows:**

```
<a href=".($row['secondary'] == 'true' ? "secondary_imgs.php?imgId=".$row['imgId']."
    &imgTitle=".$row['imgTitle']."" : "new_arrivals_img/".$row['imgURL']."").">
```

**Note:** The `a` tag *does* contain other attributes but I removed them for simplicity.

**The `href` is then appended, with the current window dimensions, using the following jQuery function:**

```
$("a[href^='secondary_imgs.php']").click(function(){
    var pageWidth = $(window).width();
    var pageHeight = $(window).height();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var idx = url.indexOf('&pageWidth=');
    if (idx != -1) {
        url = url.substr(0, idx);
    }
    url += '&pageWidth=' + pageWidth + '&pageHeight=' + pageHeight;
    $(this).attr('href', url);
});
```

My question is, what method(s) of encoding the URL should I use in this case, seeing as it will need to be done with first PHP, then jQuery/JavaScript, and finally decoded via PHP? 
Or *will* it need to be done in both PHP and jQuery/JavaScript? The original PHP `$row['imgTitle']` will *always* have at least spaces in it, and so I know it needs to be done then for sure. But seeing as the appended values will always be a variable equalling a number, does that need to be encoded as well?

I know there are several methods of encoding/decoding URLs in each coding language, and my knowledge isn't adequate enough to make the choice.

If someone could also provide an example of how I would perform each step, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) in PHP to encode URI components.

The equivalent function in javascript is [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

PHP will *decode* parameters encoded like this automatically.

So, in you PHP:

```
'<a href="..&imgTitle='.urlencode($row['imgTitle'])
```

And equivalently, in your javascript:

```
'&someparam=' + encodeURIComponent(someValue)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test it out. Curious what you think of the other persons answer above? It got votes, but he hasn't commented on *my* comment about his answer. He asked why I need it to be done in PHP. Take a look at my comment and tell me what you think.

Comment: If you could briefly let me know what I should use `urlencode` as opposed to `rawurlencode`?

Comment: Just to let you know, I used `rawurlencode()` for the PHP, and `encodeURIComponent()` for the javascript. From what I read in the documentation, this seemed to be the best approach. Again, if you feel I should have used something different, please do let me know. And I still don't know what AlienWebguy was getting at with his example.

Answer (score 5):

Why would it need to be done first with PHP? This JS urlencode function is able to be urldecoded from PHP. Encode once, decode once:

```
function urlencode (str) {
    // URL-encodes string  
    // 
    // version: 1107.2516
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode
    // +   original by: Philip Peterson
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +      input by: AJ
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +      input by: travc
    // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Lars Fischer
    // +      input by: Ratheous
    // +      reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   bugfixed by: Joris
    // +      reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // %          note 1: This reflects PHP 5.3/6.0+ behavior
    // %        note 2: Please be aware that this function expects to encode into UTF-8 encoded strings, as found on
    // %        note 2: pages served as UTF-8
    // *     example 1: urlencode('Kevin van Zonneveld!');
    // *     returns 1: 'Kevin+van+Zonneveld%21'
    // *     example 2: urlencode('http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/');
    // *     returns 2: 'http%3A%2F%2Fkevin.vanzonneveld.net%2F'
    // *     example 3: urlencode('http://www.google.nl/search?q=php.js&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a');
    // *     returns 3: 'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.nl%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dphp.js%26ie%3Dutf-8%26oe%3Dutf-8%26aq%3Dt%26rls%3Dcom.ubuntu%3Aen-US%3Aunofficial%26client%3Dfirefox-a'
    str = (str + '').toString();

    // Tilde should be allowed unescaped in future versions of PHP (as reflected below), but if you want to reflect current
    // PHP behavior, you would need to add ".replace(/~/g, '%7E');" to the following.
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').
    replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/%20/g, '+');
}
```

Comment: It needs to be done first with PHP as the `$row['imgTitle']` will be placed directly in the `href` on page load, and the `href` won't recognize the spaces in the string. Thus only the first word will be entered in the `href`, and thus, the URL.